# how to get response of email sent using sendgrid in rails app to save in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sendgrid

I have sent email through rails app using sendgrid and actionmailer, I also received the mail.
But I want status of the email sent (open,deliver,bounce..) of sendgrid in my rails app so that that response of particular  email i can save in my database.

I have followed:
https://github.com/stephenb/sendgrid 
for sending email and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

To get status of sent email, use sendgrid webhooks as described [here](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html)

Once this is setup, sendgrid will notify your url for the following events:

- Processed: Message has been received and is ready to be delivered.
- Dropped: Recipient exists in one or more of your Suppression Lists: Bounces, Spam Reports, Unsubscribes.
- Delivered: Message has been successfully delivered to the receiving server.
- Deferred: Recipient’s email server temporarily rejected message.
- Bounce: Receiving server could not or would not accept message.
- Open: Recipient has opened the HTML message.
- Click: Recipient clicked on a link within the message.
- Spam Report: Recipient marked message as spam.
- Unsubscribe: Recipient clicked on messages’s subscription management link.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, as post event url in app of sendgrid i was not able to define as I was doing localhost:3000 but by using localtunnel gem i have defined the url and put in post event url and ggot the event response

Comment: But now the issue Im getting the response from sendgrid server continously for same email with same event, any idea?? what is wrong

Comment: Sendgrid expects your api to return an HTTP 200 response, otherwise the event will be retried. Sounds like that's what is going on.

Comment: I got the response something like this                                                      Parameters: {"email"=>"mangalamelkunde@example.in", "timestamp"=>"1363934951", "smtp-id"=>"<514bfec4d78f2_125e3fedc09fac98343f6@Rohans-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>", "response"=>"250 2.0.0 OK 1363934951 gl1si1824777pac.235 - gsmtp ", "event"=>"delivered"}  now here i want save event but very next moment i get response again

Comment: Parameters: {"email"=>"mangalamelkunde@hindavi.in", "timestamp"=>"1363934950", "smtp-id"=>"<514bfec4d78f2_125e3fedc09fac98343f6@Rohans-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>", "event"=>"processed"}  that  for same mail Iam getting agaian and again same response and it is repeating  what is  wrong happening

Comment: those appear to be 2 different events related to the same message. First one is telling you message was "delivered", second is telling you it was "processed"

Answer (score 1):

You should setup the [event webhook](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) for your app.  Once you do, you'll get POSTs to your app in the format:

```
{
  "email":"foo@bar.com",
  "timestamp":1322000095,
  "unique_arg":"my unique arg",
  "category": "some_category",
  "event":"delivered"
}
```

Since you're using Rails, you should also check out [GridHook](https://github.com/injekt/gridhook).  SendGrid doesn't officially support it, but there are a number of people in the open source community working on it.  With that, you'll be able to do something like:

```
Gridhook.configure do |config|
  # The path we want to receive events
  config.event_receive_path = '/sendgrid/event'

  config.event_processor = proc do |event|
     # event is a Gridhook::Event object
     EmailEvent.create! event.attributes
  end
end
```

Comment: Just be sure, when you turn on the event notification tracking to use the 'batch' mode, otherwise you'll get one connection on your end point for every event a single message generates.
Currently the batched mode is a weird broken JSON format (each line of data you receive is its own JSON payload for that event), but we've got a new version coming out soon that will fix the JSON into a proper format.

Comment: You can request access to the beta for proper JSON if you email community@sendgrid.com though

Comment: This is totally late to the party, but SendGrid has changed the email events: They only have batch mode now.